# OrderedMap or List for Redux structure?

Tags: javascript, immutability, reactjs, redux

I'm implementing a Redux store for a React app using redux-saga for API calls. I've used Immutable.js before for other Redux-using React apps but the nature of previous projects always evidently required a normalized structure.

In this new app, the flow is less app-like and more a series of steps. There is an API call to acquire an array of (somewhat sparse) objects, expected to be about 400-600 in total. And then there is an API call per object to pick an analysis out of a very large ML-derived dataset. There is no 'bulk process' API available in the immediate term for the ML dataset (just promised in the future - their engineering resources are still focused on correctness/validity in their dataset).

I'm wondering whether to keep the initial sparse objects as an OrderedMap or a List. Essentially I need to iterate over the objects sequentially, updating each one with data acquired from the ML-dataset via a specific API call. With all objects updated, it's then delivered at once via a user download.

I'm expecting redux-saga to drive the API calls and just spit out actions to keep a progress bar on the UI updated.

This also begs the question: would you ever use an ImmutableJS List as an overall structure for Redux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and implemented this using redux-saga to run three workers to pull the required urls out of a channel.

```
export function* locationsWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest(FIND_ALL_LOCATIONS_START, handleAllLocations);
}

function* handleAllLocations() {
  try {
    // create channel to queue induvidual location requests on
    const locationChan = yield call(channel);
    yield fork(watchLocationRequests, locationChan);

    // get Immutable List of base customer ids
    const customers = yield select(getCustomersList);
    const custArr = customers.toArray();

    // put payloads into location channel
    for (let i = 0; i < custArr.length; i++) {
      const id = custArr[i].id;
      const payload = { path: `/find/${id}` }
      yield put(locationChan, payload);
    }

    // put 'end' into channel for last worker to identify finish
    yield put(locationChan, 'complete')

  } catch (error) {
      console.warn('handleAllLocations setup failed')
  }
}

function* watchLocationRequests(locationChan) {
  // create 3 worker threads
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    yield fork(handleLocationRequest, locationChan);
  }

  while (true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(FIND_LOCATION_REQUEST);
    yield put(locationChan, payload);
  }
}

// get a single location
function* handleLocationRequest(locationChan) {
  while (true) {
    const payload = yield take(locationChan)
    if (payload === 'complete') {
      yield put(findLocationsEnd());
      continue;
    }
    try {
      const response = yield call(request, payload.path);
      yield put(findLocationSuccess(payload, response.properties));
    } catch (err) {
      // update store with 'cannot find' message
      yield put(findLocationFailure(payload));
    }
  }
}
```

On writing the initial code, I realised I needed to turn the 'loading' in the UI off on completion. So last payload in the channel is a simple string. The channel handler looks out for that to send the 'ending' action. There may be a more elegant way to do that.

I've tested this and for about 250 calls, it takes about 15s (which includes a lot of UI updating) at usually < 300ms response time. Given that there's a progress bar for the user, I think this is a good first cut.

In answer to my question, I don't think there is inherently anything wrong with using an Immutable List and as demonstrated, `toArray` will simply provide a JS array.

This pattern could be appropriate for any large number of calls required but a slow api response could impact that dramatically.